# Passing data from View To Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I need view width and height to use in some calculations in activity.

In a SO Q&A i saw

```
  @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        }
```

It works but my questions:

1)how can i pass it to activity?

2) Or should i put my CustomView as a inner class into the Activity file like this

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



    int parentHeight=0;
    int parentWidth=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle aBundle=new Bundle();
        MyView myView = new MyView(this);

        Binary c=calculateCoordinates();


        aBundle.putSerializable("coordinate", c);
        myView.setData(aBundle);

        myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(myView);
    }


    public Binary calculateCoordinates(){

            Random generator = new Random();
            Binary c=new Binary();
            c.setX(generator.nextInt(parentWidth-1));
            c.setY(generator.nextInt(parentHeight-1));

        return c;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        //int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        break;
        }
        return true;
    }







    public class MyView extends View {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);            
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            Binary c = (Binary)bundle.getSerializable("coordinate");
            canvas.drawRect(c.getX(), c.getY(), c.getX()+1, c.getY()+1, paint);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth, parentHeight);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        }



        public void setData(Bundle bundle){
            this.bundle=bundle;

        }


    }



}
```

But if so i can not know when measurement have been got exactly, and if it has been got before i call the coordinate calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The `OnMeasure` function within your view will get called once the View has been placed on your actual page.

So let's say you want to get the Width and the Height when you click a button or something and want to pass those values over to another activity.

Put your view in your XML file:

```
<your.namespace.app.MyView
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/novoda.tastecard"
     android:id="@+id/myView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     ...../>
```

Then reference your View in your activity:

```
mMyView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
```

Then you can then just do:

```
int width = myView.getWidth();
int height = myView.getHeight();
```

That should return you the width and the height of the view.

Then do the following to call the new Activity with your values:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("width", width);
intent.putExtra("height", height);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks for clean explaining but even in "onPostCreate" getWidth and getHeight are 0

Answer (score 0):

**Activity Class**

add this to your OnCreate code.

```
final ViewTreeObserver obs = myView.getViewTreeObserver();
obs.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
@Override
public boolean onPreDraw () {
       int height = myView.getHeight();
       int width = myView.getWidth();

 }
```

when the View will be drawn this function will be called with the correct width and height.